# Почему не срабатывает функция js?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
var 
        loading = $("<div class='loading'></div>"),
        feed = $('#Feed'),
        feedPount = $('#FeedPoint'),
        query = { limit : 20 },
        opts = { offset: '100%' };

    Feed = {

        initwaypoint: function () {
            feedPount.waypoint(function() {
                alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
            }, opts );
        },

    }

    /* Initizalization */
    $(function() {
        Feed.initwaypoint(); // Такой вызов не срабатывает при каждом достижении конечной точки
    });
```

А такой код работает:

```
$(function() {
               feedPount.waypoint(function() {
                    alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
                }, opts );
});
```

В чем особенность вызова? Как сделать, чтобы первый вариант стал рабочим?

Comment: У вас случаем первая часть не грузится до документа? Мне кажется, разницы нет, сделайте jsfiddle, чтобы было понятно, есть ли ошибка.  И поправьте название переменной - глаза режет.

Comment: На fiddle пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/06o0ucve/2/
Не работает

Comment: Может все, включая Feed прототип, обвернуть в $(function() {});?

Comment: > TypeError: feedPoint.waypoint is not a function

Пример на feedle должен демонстрировать проблему.

Comment: Но вообще да, то, что обращается к DOM, должно быть завернуто в document.ready(function(){}) aka $(funciton(){}) aka jQuery(function($){})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь переменные объявляются и сразу пытаются получить значение методами библиотеки jQuery, которая еще не догрузилась на момент объявления глобальных переменных. Надо так:

```
var loading, feed, feedPount,
    query = { limit : 20 },
    opts = { offset: '100%' };

$(function() {
    loading = $("<div class='loading'></div>");
    feed = $('#Feed');
    feedPount = $('#FeedPoint');

    Feed = {
        initwaypoint: function () {
            feedPount.waypoint(function() {
                alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
            }, opts );
        }
    };

    feedPount.waypoint(function() {
        alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
    }, opts );  
});
```

Но в то же время имеет место каша с областями видимости переменных, надо бы причесать.

Comment: > пытаются получить значение от жквери, которая еще не запустилась

это что зан новое слово ? кто ещё не запустился ? (я имею ввиду не "жквери", а вообще явление.

вы типа вот это "$(function(){})" называете **запуском** jQuery ??

Comment: то минусуешь и не нравится что без коммента, то прокоментишь почему минус и обижаются... вы в семинарии что-ли учились чтобы про гордыню рассуждать ? Исправьте фактическую ошибку, вам это так важно чтобы обман был в ответе ?. 

> не библиотека не догрузилась, а документ. jQuery сама по себе догрузилась, иначе вы не смогли бы сделать $()